# How to use unattended.xml to install Windows Server 2016 with RDP enabled?

Tags: installation, windows-server-2016

I have a headless server. I'd like to install Windows Server 2016 on it. And RDP needs to be enabled so I can log on to it with remote desktop later. I believe I could do that with unattended.xml. But the file is very complicated. Is there a template with RDP enabled and everything else left in default state? I'd like to customize the server later. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a start. But there are some settings like NextHopAddress which I don't know what they are for. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36609.windows-server-2016-unattended-installation.aspx